# What's the best way to replace a character in [C] with characters from column A+B

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I am using pandas and I got stack on the following task.

I have the following table:

```
CHROM   POS     SNP
chr1    931131  ?
chr1    959265  ?
chr1    970922  ?
chr1    973693  rs3892467
chr1    973858  rs3829740
```

And everytime that the value in [SNP] is ='?' I would like to change it by joying the values in the other two columns so that the output would be like this:

```
CHROM   POS     SNP
chr1    931131  chr1:931131
chr1    959265  chr1:959265
chr1    970922  chr1:970922
chr1    973693  rs3892467
chr1    973858  rs3829740
```

Thank you in advance
Gabriella

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['SNP']=df['SNP'].mask(df['SNP'].eq('?'),df['CHROM'].add(':')+df['POS'].astype(str))

print(df)
```

---

```
  CHROM     POS          SNP
0  chr1  931131  chr1:931131
1  chr1  959265  chr1:959265
2  chr1  970922  chr1:970922
3  chr1  973693    rs3892467
4  chr1  973858    rs3829740
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
df.loc[df['SNP'] == '?', 'SNP'] = df[['CHROM', 'POS']].apply(':'.join, axis = 1)
```

You get

```
   CHROM    POS     SNP
0   chr1    970922  chr1:970922
1   chr1    970922  rs3892467
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the fastest method is "where":

```
df["SNP"]=df.SNP.where( df.SNP.ne("?"), df.CHROM+":"+df.POS )
```

or if POS is of type int:

```
df["SNP"]=df.SNP.where( df.SNP.ne("?"), df.CHROM+":"+df.POS.astype(str) )
```